# how to retrieve same image to android phones with different screen densities+json

Tags: android, json, image

I am a beginner to android development field.I need to create an app in which the contents are taken from web.So i need to retrieve images from a url using json.I know how to retrieve image using JSON.But my problem is my app should supports phones and tablets.So the image should fit into the appropriate devices.So my question **how do i retrieve same image into different screen densities using JSON?**.***So do i need to keep different sized images URL's for retrieving images into corresponding device(by using some checking to find whether the device is tablet or phone) or storing only single large image in URL and after retrieving it,and croping it to fit the container?***.Please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different images for different devices as recommended by android. You can place images for different densities e.g hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdp etc on your server.

Now check density and download image accordingly. Here is example how you can check density of device

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    // ...
    break;
}
```